# Emacs flyspell choices buffer hidden under tabbar

Tags: flyspell, tabbar

When using flyspell in Xemacs to correct spelling the buffer showing the list of choices is partially hidden under the tabbar elements at the top of the frame - I loose the bottom line of choices. Yup, I use tabbar having got used to it in Aquamacs before learning to avoid anything out of Cupertino. All is fine if I use flyspell from Emacs in the terminal as tabbar does not load. How do I set the height of the Choices buffer to be big enough or how do I force tabbar lower when the choices buffer is open?

[image]

Comment: So you are saying that it is not related to the size of the frame? If you enlarge the frame, the last line of choices is still obscured? BTW, AFAICT, they are not hidden behind the tab bar (unless there is a line before the (0) choice which seems unlikely to me): the last line is hidden behind the modeline of the `*Choices*` buffer.

Comment: Depending upon the word being spell checked, at one time or another, the number of available choices will exceed the available buffer space.  The frame in the picture is particularly small, with maybe 6 or seven lines in the working buffer; and, it is possible that Emacs is also trying to maintain a certain size of that working buffer, rather than reducing it to less than 6 or seven lines for the benefit of the choices buffer containing less likely words on line 4 of the spelling choices.

Comment: Thanks NickD for pointing out that the obscure is behind the modeline of the Choices buffer but the Choices buffer always seems to be half a line too small. I've tried to enlarge the frame size (thanks lawlist) but it makes no difference. It also makes no difference how large the main working buffer is (ie one line of text for 1000's). I'm unable to change the size of the Choices buffer by dragging - the cursor changes to the updown arrows but the modeline won't move. It's OK for many lines of choices but hopeless for only one!